# Why 嘊 character gets URL encoded as %E5%98%8A?

Tags: unicode, utf-8, character-encoding

I have poking around Unicode and UTF-8 for a while and don't fully understand how URL encoding work for character like 嘊.

So, 嘊 is U+560A as Unicode code, &#22026 as HTML decimal representation and &#x560A as HTML hex (correct me if I am wrong). So why would browser will URL encode is as %E5%98%8A?

My guess is that 嘊 needs more than 7 bit to render (so we are out of ASCII range), so 嘊 character consists of few bytes (one of them will "shift" to another codes set) and %E5%98%8A is three hex numbers that represents 3 decimals 229, 152, 10 and that sequence of decimals represents 嘊 if we try to convert it to UTF-8 charset.

Am I right? Thanks in advance for clarification!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like the confusions stems from mixing "Unicode" and "UTF-8" in meaning. Unicode is a standard that basically assigns a number to every character (*). That is what U+560A is: The Unicode codepoint 560A (which is just hex for 22026). The HTML/XML decimal and hexadecimal character entities directly use that value without any encoding, that's why you can just provide that number.

"Unicode" itself is not yet an encoding. That means it does not define a unique mapping of how to map those characters to bytes.

UTF-8 is one such mapping which basically tries to map each Unicode codepoint to as anywhere between 1 and 4 bytes (the higher the codepoint, the longer the byte sequence).

URL encoding handles text with a specific encoding, so it has to encode the bytes produced by UTF-8.

(*) it's a lot more complicated and they define much more than just the characters, but for the purpose of this answer this is close enough.

Comment: Thanks! What do you mean by "URL encoding handles text with a specific encoding"? Why URL encodes bytes produces by UTF-8 for 嘊 but not for A symbol? Why A is directly passed to URL without encoding?

Comment: @NikitaShchypyplov: `A` *can* be URL encoded (it would be `%41`), but since it falls in the range of ASCII-encodable characters (anything with a Unicode codepoint <= 127, basically) it doesn't need to be encoded and can be transferred as-is.

Comment: Thanks, last question if you don't mind: could you please on your phrase "bytes produced by UTF-8." - it means that when I typed in <input type="text' /> 嘊 as a value 
 I see this glyph, but internally I really typed 3 hex numbers and browser does lookup for meta tag for encoding (UTF-8 in our example) and HTML parser will convert these numbers to glyph? And glyph is "rendered" by font that installed on the machine?

Comment: That question opens a can of worms and can't trivially be answered in a comment (or even an SO question), as it touches so many different areas (HTML, HTTP, text layout and encoding, each of which worth several books full of details). Try [this article](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/) for a starter.

Comment: Cool, I will give it a shot!

Comment: @JoachimSauer "*but since it falls in the range of ASCII-encodable characters (anything with a Unicode codepoint <= 127, basically) it doesn't need to be encoded and can be transferred as-is*" - that is true for `A` specifically, and other alpha-numeric characters, but it is not true for ALL ascii characters. SOME characters are reserved for syntax purposes in a URL. Such characters, when used as data in a context that would confuse the syntax, must be url-encoded as well.

Answer (score 3):

As you say the code point for 嘊 is U+560A. The UTF-8 encoding of this code point is 0xE5 0x98 0x8A and it is this which is then % encoded into the URL.

Comment: Thanks for an answer!